# AsyncTask в BlockingObservable ничего не возвращает

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, rxjava

Хочу получить список исполнителей из аудиозаписей вк. вместо респонса тишина, "INONCOMPLETE" так и не выводится. При чем если вместо toBlocking использую onSubscribe, или кидаю Observable без Blocking в zip, все работает

```
bands = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<VKResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Subscriber<? super VKResponse> subscriber) {
                    VKApi.audio().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                            super.onComplete(response);
                            System.out.println("INONCOMPLETE ");
                            subscriber.onNext(response);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
                            super.attemptFailed(request, attemptNumber, totalAttempts);
                            System.out.println("attemptFailed");
                            subscriber.onError(new Exception("attemptFailed"));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(VKError error) {
                            super.onError(error);
                            System.out.println(error.toString());
                            subscriber.onError(new Exception(error.toString()));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
                            super.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .flatMap(vkResponse -> Observable.from((VKList<VKApiAudio>) vkResponse.parsedModel))
            .flatMap(vkApiAudio -> Observable.just(vkApiAudio.artist))
            .distinct()
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
```

Comment: ```toBlocking()``` заблокирует поток. Вы уверены что это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: именно это мне и нужно. заблокировать поток, пока не будет получен результат

Comment: Тогда какой смысл в rx если вы блокируете поток? К тому же если вы блокируете UI поток, то это является ошибкой. Возможно поэтому у вас и ошибка, т.к. выпадает исключение из-за взаимодействия с сетью в UI потоке.

Comment: а вы этот код в ui-потоке вызываете? Тогда оно не взлетит, поскольку колбеки vk-api вызываются в ui-потоке, а он у вас заблокирован.

Comment: спасибо, понятно.

Comment: VKApi.audio().get().executeSyncWithListener - то что помогло